# OR-Tools TSP with Multiple time windows on Locations or Vehicle

Tags: python, or-tools, traveling-salesman, vehicle-routing

I'm working on a TSP spanning through multiple days. All the locations can be visited **09:00-17:00 Mon-Fri** and **09:00-13:00 on Sat**. Sunday is a day off. To achieve this, I have two options in mind and I'm looking for the correct approach.

1. Specify **time_dimension** for each locations' time window in which I'll need to remove the intervals, e.g. **17:00 Mon - 09:00 Tues**, etc. for each day, to make the locations available only within the given time window
2. Instead of time windows for locations, specify the work hours for the vehicle as an interval. In other words, make the locations available at all times, but set the vehicle's working hours only within the time frames.

Which of these is the correct approach and how to achieve this?

Comment: Either . It depends whether your drivers can do overnighting and park up. I don't use OR-Tools for this, but it's a fundamental issue. If you set the driver shifts to cover the whole week, be careful that they don't sneak in driving time overnight. Their hours are heavily regulated, at least in the EU

Comment: There's an [or.SE] beta site that would probably fit your question better.